# Assuming yesterday I met your brother, I would say

Tags: conditional-constructions, will-would

Person A: What is the meaning of "bump into someone"?

1. Person B: If I **met** your brother somewhere unexpectedly, I **would** say, "I bumped into him yesterday."

Here I'm only interested in sentence (1).

Is this a valid *second conditional* where the sentence in quotes uses "real" past tense (bumped into), with *yesterday* referring to the time of meeting? (**Both** "met" and "would" are *unreal*)

Or

Does the condition clause of (1) assume a real past situation where the speaker met *your* brother, and the result clause talks about a present or future unreal time? ("met" and the sentence in quotes are real, **but** "would" is unreal)

Something like: ***Assuming** yesterday I **met** your brother somewhere unexpectedly, I **would** say, "I bumped into him (yesterday)."*

Comment: *If I **had** met your brother somewhere unexpectedly* - where Past Perfect coupled with ***if*** describes an "unreal, counterfactual" situation in the past (speaker definitely *didn't* meet addressee's brother yesterday). It's entirely a stylistic choice whether to extend the Perfect form to *I would **have said...*** In practice, nobody really cares about whether speaker's talking about what he would say ***right now***, as opposed to what he would have said at some point in the "hypothetical" past, (before now, but after the hypothetical meeting).

Comment: OK, you're talking about it from a "hypothetical **past**" point of view. What if we talk about the same thing from a "hypothetical **future**" point of view, as in sentence (1) in the OP, using a pure *second conditional*? Wouldn't it be correct?

Comment: I have precisely ***zero*** interest in "numbered conditionals" - for any learner capable of interacting in English on a site like this, they're such a limited subset of real-world possibilities that all they do is confuse people. But to *talk about the same thing from a "hypothetical future" point of view* wouldn't be your cited example #1 in the OP. The closest I can get to a "hypothetical future" would be *If I **were to meet*** (future) or ***were to have met*** (past in the future) - but to be honest, concepts like Past and Future aren't very useful when the context is ***Unreal***.

Comment: Thank you very much! Since you say you have no interest in "numbered conditionals", would you accept this *mixed* (real + unreal) conditional in the context of the OP: *If (or assuming) yesterday I **met** (real) your brother somewhere unexpectedly, I **would** (unreal) (now) say, "I bumped into him (yesterday)."*